# ruby on rails add a column after a specific column name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I tried to add a column to a table after a specific column in the table.
Here is what I did:

```
rails generate migration add_reaction_id_to_patient_allergies reaction_id: integer :after => 'patient_id'
```

Here is what my migration file looks like:

```
class AddReactionIdToPatientAllergies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :patient_allergies, :reaction_id, :string
    add_column :patient_allergies, :integer, :string
    add_column :patient_allergies, :, :after
    add_column :patient_allergies, :=, :string
  end
end
```

I dont think the command went well. I see an '=' in the above file. I do not think it should be there. Can someone tell me if I missed anything?

If so , how do I undo the above?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I doubt it allowed you to actually `rails db:migrate` this migration, so you shouldn't have to roll back. Just remove the bottom three `add_column`s and replace the top one with

```
add_column :patient_allergies, :reaction_id, :integer, after: :patient_id
```

and it should be fine to migrate. For future reference, here's what that command you entered should look like:

```
rails generate migration add_reaction_id_to_patient_allergies reaction_id:integer
```

The space before `integer` made the generator think it was a new column. Sadly you can't use Ruby syntax (`a => b`) on the command line either.

Comment: @michael Just to add one more thing to this great answer, to undo a successful but unwanted migration you can do rake db:rollback - this reverses the most recent migration. You can step further back by repeating it. I often find myself undoing to make small tweaks, such as setting default value or column order

Comment: The `:after` option doesn't look to be included in the [API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html), at least for Rails 4.2.3. Found out after trying: the migration went ok but the ordering was not applied.

Comment: @nandinga It looks like the [ColumnDefinition](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb#L13) class in the latest Rails still supports the `after` option, though I haven't tested this on the last few releases of Rails.

Comment: Apparently this doesn't work if you're using Postgres.  See http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3276/how-can-i-specify-the-position-for-a-new-column-in-postgresql