# Using "after" does not have any effect in a Rails Migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration, ruby-on-rails-7, ruby-3

I have generated the migration file and added t.string :address. before ''' rails db:migrate''' I added the line-

```
add_column :users, :address, :string, limit: 10, after: :email
```

*but it was added last on the table*

```
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.string "address", limit: 10
```

*Expected as*

```
t.string "email"
t.string "address", limit: 10
```

**Is there any way to cop with this problem**

Comment: Which database adapter are you using?

Comment: The order of the columns in your migrations, schema dumps and in the database itself are completely inconsequential

Comment: Having a look into the documentation https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_column I doubt that "after" does have any effect as it's not documented

Comment: Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/15481778/4758119
If you're using postgres it doesn't work

Comment: @JamesHibbard sqlite

Answer (score 0):

The `after` option for `add_column` is not supported by SQLite, it's specific to MySQL. As SQLite does not support reordering of columns natively, if the column order is crucial, you would need to recreate the table with the desired column order.

As others have mentioned in the comments, column order in a table is not significant in terms of functionality. So if this is just for aesthetic reasons, it's usually not worth the effort to make the change.